# Is the editor Atom able to open projects on a remote server?

Tags: atom-editor

Atom is able to open a project, and to show the whole tree of the project on the left side, a really nice feature.

Now I'm using SSH on Host OS to access a Guest OS (say Red Hat Enterprise Linux, RHEL) on Virtualbox, is there a way of Atom located in Host OS to open a project located on RHEL?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well yes there is!

You just need to configure sshfs, optionally with autofs. Then you can access the files as if they are stored locally. I've used this with Atom and it works seamlessly.

### Instructions for Ubuntu

#### Install sshfs

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

#### Mount the remote directory on a local mountpoint

```
$ sshfs [user@]host:[dir] mountpoint
```

### Combining it with autofs

The following link has instructions for a setup using autofs.

**Note**: This requires you to setup SSH for the **root** user.

http://www.mccambridge.org/blog/2007/05/totally-seamless-sshfs-under-linux-using-fuse-and-autofs/

Additionally to that post, I've added some tricks for an even more seamless experience.

#### Enhance performance

I've noticed a significant performance boost by adding this SSH config to `/root/.ssh/config`:

```
Ciphers arcfour
Compression no
```

**Note**: This does make the connection less secure.

#### Make it appear as a disk

If you set the mount point to a directory in `/media`, the mount point will show up as a disk in your file browser. For example `/media/sshfs`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed for developing on a raspberry pi, thank you!

Comment: It won't support delete so well on Mac :(

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the [Remote sync](https://atom.io/packages/remote-sync) plugin for this. I have a python environment set up on a linux box and i connect to it from my PC.

It allows me to upload changes automatically when i save a file and also define files to be monitored for changes.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% what you're looking for, but there's the Remote-Edit package: https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit

This will allow you to define the connection parameters for the server, and will then allow you to browse and edit the files found on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Complement to Remco's sshfs answer above:

If you use different users in the client and server hosts, consider using  the 'idmap' option of sshfs.

I use different users in my working host and in the development or testing VMs.

Example:

using option '-o idmap=user' will automatically translate UID/GID of the remote host to the UID/GID of the connecting user in the local host

Files owned by remote user (*devuser*) in remote host (*devhost1*) will appear as belonging to the connecting user (*locuser*) in local host (*clienthost*)

```
locuser@clienthost:~$ sshfs devuser@devhost1:/var/www  ~/dev/www -o idmap=user

locuser@clienthost:~$ ls -lR ~/dev/www
(...)
-rw-rw-r-- 1 locuser locuser   269 abr  1 11:37 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 locuser locuser   249 abr  3 03:59 page1.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 locuser locuser  1118 abr  2 15:07 page2.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 locuser locuser   847 abr  3 03:20 page3.html
(...)
```

The mapping can also be made explicit (*userx* <-> *usery*).  For more details see man sshfs

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer because none of the other answers worked for me.

- Mounting as a directory & browsing with atom (@Remco Haszing answer) was a brilliant one.

but in my case, atom wants to index all of the remote project & its a heavy one. and it gets not responding.

- using [remote-sync](https://atom.io/packages/remote-sync) package was good when you working locally then want to upload the files to server.
- Actually the [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit) is the package meant to do this job. (editing files remotely on ssh)
  the problem with this is, it has been abandon.

These help me as its replacements:

https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit-ni

https://atom.io/packages/remote-editor