# How to connect the Atom Editor with a remote server?

Tags: atom-editor, remote-server

I've tried looking at other questions here with similar problems, but unfortunately I haven't been able to solve this issue.

For some basic background info, I'm currently using a PC in a lab and the lab has GPU servers somewhere in the institution. I'm attempting to connect the Atom Editor to the remote host. My PC uses Windows 10 and the remote server is Ubuntu 16.04.

I've looked at thie [remote-atom guide](https://atom.io/packages/remote-atom) but for some reason the "Start Server" option is not working. I've also tried to do what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39033817/is-the-editor-atom-able-to-open-projects-on-a-remote-server) has stated, but unfortunately I don't have `sudo` permission.

Would there be another way that I can connect Atom remotely? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily connect to remote FTP using atom even if you do not have any sudo permission on the sudo server.

On Remote server:
- Create a rsa key (ssh-keygen -t rsa)
- add the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys file
- download the private key to you local desktop

On local machine > open Atom editor:
- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to open the 'ftp-remote-edit' 
- add the server if not present already

[Atom editor: remote server configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRAYd.png)

That's it, you are ready to connect and edit files.

Other viable option is using VS code using winScp.